# Как реализовать анимацию?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-animation

Как написать такую-же анимацию, как в первом блоке на сайте, что текст разъезжается? https://otherside.xyz/
Искал в интернете, всё ссылалось на использование REACT, но для меня это не выход.

Comment: ну, реакт нужен не для анимаций. Я бы использовал GSAP для упрощения жизни

Comment: Там это, похоже, в threejs сделано, но можно просто png на канвас кинуть, при скролле отзеркаливать и сдвигать с одновременным масштабированием.

Answer (score 1):

самый простой вариант - сделать 2 svg картинки, одну отзеркалить.
Потом через js добавлять какой-то класс, например, animated.

```
<div class="title">
  <div class="text-wrap">
   <svg class="text1"></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="text-wrap">
   <svg class="text2"></svg>
  </div>
</div>



.text-wrap {overflow: hidden}

.text1 {transform: translateY(100px)}
.text2 {transform: translateY(-100px)}

.animated .text1, .animated .text2 {transform: translateY(0)}
```

Если не хочешь svg, то бери обычный текст, зеркаль его (решения можно найти на [codepen](https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=mirror%20text)). И через transform + perspective задать нужную форму.